# Set up DNS over HTTPS in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dns, https

Trying to enable DNS over HTTPS in Chrome (ver. 80) on Windows 10 Pro. Tried turning it on at

> chrome://flags/#dns-over-https

[image: Enabling DNS over https]

as per a [FOSSBYTES article](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-on-chrome-firefox-edge-brave/) but as per https://1.1.1.1/help it is not enabled.

Also, as per https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-doh-in-google-chrome/ , tried appending this

`--enable-features="dns-over-https<DoHTrial" --force-fieldtrials="DoHTrial/Group1" --force-fieldtrial-params="DoHTrial.Group1:server/https%3A%2F%2F1.1.1.1%2Fdns-query/method/POST`

to the Target field of the shortcut which launches Chrome by editing its Properties field. Shut down Chrome and the PC, relaunched Chrome after rebooting, but when I check it at https://1.1.1.1/help , it's still not enabled.

[image: not enabled]

Set it up in Firefox and Brave with no problem, BTW, exactly as [FOSSBYTES instructions](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-on-chrome-firefox-edge-brave/) described. For those browsers, the Cloudflare [confirmation page](https://1.1.1.1/help)  shows **Using DNS over HTTPS (DOH)** as **Yes**. Have not tried Chromium yet.

How may I configure Google Chrome (and also Chromium) to use DNS over HTTPS?

Comment: What's the result in Firefox and Chromium (the blue icon one)?

Comment: See next to last graf of question.

Comment: All DNSCrypt clients now support DoH out of the box. Install a client for your platform and you will have DoH system wide! There are many DNS requests that don't come from your browser. https://www.dnscrypt.org/

Comment: Point well taken.

Comment: Try to use Cloudflare DNS in your network settings, it makes change for me https://1.1.1.1/dns/#setup-instructions